# How to know that camera is currently being used by another application with UWP?

Tags: windows, camera, uwp, c++-cx

I am trying to show error message "Cannot setup camera; currently being using" when there is already a process running the camera. I have the code that starts the preview using the MediaCapture and it works fine when running without another application using camera. I do get the exception

0x40080201: WinRT originate error (parameters: 0xC00D3704, 0x00000049, 0x10EFF1CC)

in my logs but my try catch block doesn't catch the error.

```
create_task(_mediaCapture->StartPreviewToCustomSinkAsync(encoding_profile, media_sink)).then([this, &hr](task<void>& info) {
    try {
         info.get();
    } catch (Exception^ e) {
        hr = e->HResult;
    }
}).wait();
```

Answer (score 1):

[StartPreviewAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.mediacapture#Windows_Media_Capture_MediaCapture_StartPreviewAsync) method will throw a **FileLoadException** if another app has exclusive control of the capture device. We can catch this error to alert the user that the camera is currently being used by another application. A simple sample can be found at [Use MediaCapture to start the preview stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/simple-camera-preview-access#use-mediacapture-to-start-the-preview-stream).

However, this is a C# sample and `FileLoadException` is what used in .Net. For C++/CX, we can check the HRESULT value which should be `0x80070020`. Following is the simple sample in C++/CX version.

***MainPage.xaml***

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <CaptureElement Name="PreviewControl" Stretch="Uniform"/>
    <Button Click="Button_Click">Click</Button>
</Grid>
```

***MainPage.xaml.h***

```
public ref class MainPage sealed
{
public:
    MainPage();

private:
    // Prevent the screen from sleeping while the camera is running
    Windows::System::Display::DisplayRequest^ _displayRequest;

    // MediaCapture
    Platform::Agile<Windows::Media::Capture::MediaCapture^> _mediaCapture;

    void Button_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e);
};
```

***MainPage.xaml.cpp***

```
MainPage::MainPage()
    : _mediaCapture(nullptr)
    , _displayRequest(ref new Windows::System::Display::DisplayRequest())
{
    InitializeComponent();
}


void MainPage::Button_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    _mediaCapture = ref new Windows::Media::Capture::MediaCapture();
    create_task(_mediaCapture->InitializeAsync())
        .then([this](task<void> previousTask) {
        try
        {
            previousTask.get();
            _displayRequest->RequestActive();
            Windows::Graphics::Display::DisplayInformation::AutoRotationPreferences = Windows::Graphics::Display::DisplayOrientations::Landscape;
            PreviewControl->Source = _mediaCapture.Get();
            create_task(_mediaCapture->StartPreviewAsync())
                .then([this](task<void>& previousTask)
            {
                try
                {
                    previousTask.get();
                }
                catch (Exception^ exception)
                {
                    if (exception->HResult == 0x80070020)
                    {
                        auto messageDialog = ref new Windows::UI::Popups::MessageDialog("Cannot setup camera; currently being using.");
                        create_task(messageDialog->ShowAsync());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        catch (AccessDeniedException^)
        {
            auto messageDialog = ref new Windows::UI::Popups::MessageDialog("The app was denied access to the camera.");
            create_task(messageDialog->ShowAsync());
        }
    });
}
```

[StartPreviewToCustomSinkAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.mediacapture#Windows_Media_Capture_MediaCapture_StartPreviewToCustomSinkAsync_Windows_Media_MediaProperties_MediaEncodingProfile_Windows_Media_IMediaExtension_) method is similar to [StartPreviewAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.mediacapture#Windows_Media_Capture_MediaCapture_StartPreviewAsync) method and can also throw a **FileLoadException**. You should be able to handle it using the same way. For more info, please also see [Handle changes in exclusive control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/simple-camera-preview-access#handle-changes-in-exclusive-control).