# Detect if user has muted/unmuted microphone in messengers (Skype, Discord, Telegram) with C# on application level?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, winapi

I am writing a program to collect a Windows user actions data: clicks, outlook meetings, microphone and webcamera usage, etc. Something close to key logger, but with additions.

I have a task to collect data if user has muted or unmuted his microphone during a call in messengers: like Skype, Telegram or Discord, for example.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61132854/how-can-i-determine-if-a-webcam-is-in-use-on-windows-10-without-activating-the-c) question, i can collect data from registry by path

> **\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CapabilityAccessManager\ConsentStore\microphone\NonPackaged**

There is written data of which apps have asked access to a microphone  and device usage time start and stop.
But it does not tell if user`s microphone was actually used (user could mute it during a call).

Is there any way to get data if users microphone was actually used and was not turned off during calls?
Any low level Win32 functions?
Is it even possible, or applications microphone data stream cannot be accessed?

Comment: I typically mute the microphone via the hardware. The OS does not know anything about that i did that and if i put a cap on the camera the OS will also not know.

Comment: There 's a complex MIXER API which does what you want at the Win32 level.

Comment: @Ralf, yes, if user puts a cap on the camera it will be considered to be used, but in reality camera does not work. I think this may be a weak part, that users can use)
But i know, that there is a way to catch a hardware event when mic or cam device is unplugged from PC.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis are you sure this will help?
In my case, microphone will not be muted in a mixer, so i guess mixer api is useless.
Or it can detect if application muted microphone stream?

Comment: It turns out, that registry by path \SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CapabilityAccessManager\ConsentStore\webcam\NonPackaged actually writes correct data if camera is turned off/on during a call. I will edit question.

Comment: According to the thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75480900/how-to-get-current-microphone-state-within-a-call-muted-unmuted. It seems that there is no api to get the current microphone state within a call.

Comment: So, this means, that i have to use messengers` api to get state of muted/unmuted microphone in application, right?
There is no possible way to get audio stream in app and check if it is muted somehow?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, it may be hard to get your requirement.